# python script to click button

Tags: python, button, scripting, web, click

I have this cod working for long time for a game web site but now they changed the way it should be clicked :-

```
def formRaid():
    #print formerID
    one = 1
    while one == 1:
        try:
            global _startTime
            _startTime = datetime.datetime.now()

            formpage = alo("http://"+server+".outwar.com/formraid.php?target=" + bossToRaidId+"&suid="+FORMER_ID).read()
            codeID = formpage.split('codeid" value="')[1].split('">')[0]

            Form = alo2("http://"+server+".outwar.com/formraid.php?target=" + bossToRaidId, "target=" + bossToRaidId + "&codeid=" + codeID + "&formtime=3&submit=Launch!").read()

            global RAID_ID, RAID_NAME
            RAID_ID = getRaidID(Form)
            RAID_NAME = getRaidName(Form)

            print ""
            print "***" + RAID_NAME + " Formed."
            one = 0
            return True

        except IndexError:
            print "Forming Error, retrying...."
            time.sleep(1)
```

Now i have to click a button to go one again and the information for this button is :-

```
<input type="submit" value="Join this Raid!" name="submit">
```

How i can make the click that used in :-

```
formpage = alo("http://"+server+".outwar.com/formraid.php?target=" + bossToRaidId+"&suid="+FORMER_ID).read()
codeID = formpage.split('codeid" value="')[1].split('">')[0]
```

or the one that used in :-

```
Form = alo2("http://"+server+".outwar.com/formraid.php?target=" + bossToRaidId, "target=" + bossToRaidId + "&codeid=" + codeID + "&formtime=3&submit=Launch!").read()
```

Click that button instead of what it did before ??

Comment: Is the button part of a form? What URL does the form point to?

Answer (score 0):

opener.open("http://"+server+".outwar.com/formraid.php?target=" + bossToRaidId + "&suid="+FORMER_ID, "formtime=3&message=&bomb=none&submit=Launch!")

only works for 2.7 python